# Rails , enum role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, devise

Create enum with User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  enum role: [:user, :manager]
  has_many :tickets
end
```

and when i will sign_up as user.manager i get error

```
undefined method `manager?' for nil:NilClass
```

my views **_header.html.haml**

```
%div
  .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-inverse
    %ul
      -if user_signed_in?
        %li= link_to 'New ticket', new_ticket_path, class: 'btn btn-danger'
        %li= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path,
                                class: 'btn btn-primary',
                                method: :delete
      -elsif current_user.manager?
        %li= link_to 'All tickets', '#'
      -else
        %li= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path, class: 'btn btn-primary'
        %li= link_to 'Log in', new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  -if user_signed_in?
    # skipped
  -elsif current_user.manager?
    # skipped
```

What you write is illogical, since `current_user` is only defined, when user **is signed in**.

Your `elsif` is invoked when no user *is signed in*, so will throw an error, obviously, since it is calling a method on a `nil` (no `current_user`).

Answer (score 1):

To add `@Andrey`'s answer, you'll want to use the following:

```
%div
  .navbar.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-inverse
    %ul
      -if user_signed_in?
         = content_tag :li, link_to('New ticket', new_ticket_path, class: 'btn btn-danger')
         = content_tag :li, link_to('Log out', destroy_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :delete)
         = content_tag :li, link_to('All tickets', '#') if current_user.manager?
      -else
        = content_tag :li, link_to('Sign up', new_user_registration_path, class: 'btn btn-primary')
        = content_tag :li, link_to('Log in', new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-primary')
```